# What means the "SP Entity/IdP Audience" parameter in saml configuration for service provider?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

In documentation for configuration saml protocol for Looker I find **SP Entity/IdP Audience** property and that confuse me so much because I don't understand which element in saml request this property correspond to. The article explain how to configure Looker as service provider. But as I know we don't send in request to identity provider any information about requester except **Issuer**.

Besides it has very strange description:
"**SP Entity/IdP Audience**: This field is not required by Looker, but many IdPs will require this field. If you enter a value in this field, that value will be sent to your IdP as Looker’s **Entity ID** in authorization requests. In that case, Looker will only accept authorization responses that have this value as the Audience. If your IdP requires an Audience value, enter that string here.
This value is also used as the **issuer** field in messages sent to the IdP. So, if your IdP complains that it is receiving a message without an **issuer** then you need to fill this in. You can use whatever string your IdP might require. In most cases you can use “Looker”. If this field is present then your IdP must send it as the **audience** field in the message it sends back to Looker."

I thought that **EntityId** is the value that send in **Issuer** element but this description make fill myself very stupid. I mean I can't find anything appropriate in specification. So can some one explain meaning of this mysterious property?

[Here](https://docs.looker.com/admin-options/security/saml-auth) is documentation which I token about and saml protocol [specification](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/56776/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-07.pdf)(3.2 Requests and Responses).

I should explain that I don't use Looker but I look for examples of saml configurations in different services! We plan to add saml supporting for our product so I make some research.

Answer (score 1):

(1) We can obtain the information below from the link provided by you for the saml protocol specification (3.2 Requests and Responses).
(I) Internet2 is one of core contributors of the SAML protocol specification.
(II) 3.2 Requests and Responses
3.2.1 Complex Type RequestAbstractType

```
ID [Required]
Version [Required]
IssueInstant [Required]
Destination [Optional]
Consent [Optional]
<saml:Issuer> [Optional] Identifies the entity that generated the request message.
<ds:Signature> [Optional]
<Extensions> [Optional]
```

Quote your post "I thought that **EntityId** is the value that send in **Issuer** element".
**Response**:
Yes. You are correct. SAML SP **Entity ID** is sent in **Issuer** element of SAML authorization request to SAML IdP (as shown by SAML request sent by Shibboleth SAML SP "https://mycompany.example.org" later on).

(2) **Question**: "What means the “SP Entity/IdP Audience” parameter in saml configuration for service provider?"

Quote "**SP Entity**/**IdP Audience**: This field is not required by Looker, but many IdPs will require this field. If you enter a value in this field, that value will be sent to your IdP as Looker’s **Entity ID** in authorization requests. In that case, Looker will only accept authorization responses that have this value as the Audience. If your IdP requires an Audience value, enter that string here. This value is also used as the issuer field in messages sent to the IdP. So, if your IdP complains that it is receiving a message without an issuer then you need to fill this in. You can use whatever string your IdP might require. In most cases you can use “Looker”. If this field is present then your IdP must send it as the audience field in the message it sends back to Looker."

**Answer**:

(I) SAML SP Looker does NOT send SP Entity ID in Issuer element of SAML authorization request to SAML IdP if you leave "**SP Entity/IdP Audience (Optional)**" field empty by default.

(II) "if your IdP complains that it is receiving a message without an issuer then you need to fill this in."
 
This means that you need to fill SAML **SP Entity ID** (e.g., "https://mycompany.looker.com/") into "**SP Entity/IdP Audience (Optional)**" field through Looker Admin GUI so that Looker can send **SP Entity ID** (e.g., "https://mycompany.looker.com/") in **Issuer** element of SAML authorization request to SAML IdP.

(III) "If this field is present then your IdP must send it as the audience field in the message it sends back to Looker."
 
This means that SAML IdP will send SAML **SP Entity ID** (e.g., "https://mycompany.looker.com/") in the **audience** field of SAML response to Looker SAML SP.

(3) **SAML Example**: Quote "Okta now offers a Looker App, which is the recommended way to configure Looker and Okta together."

(I) [How to build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP) at GitHub repository allows you to run Shibboleth SAML IdP (parallel to Okta SAML IdP) and Shibboleth SAML SP (parallel to Looker SAML SP) on your own machine.
Internet2 contributed significant resources to the development of Shibboleth SAML IdP and Shibboleth SAML SP.

(II) Without loss of generality, we make a demo on SAML communication between Okta SAML IdP and Shibboleth SAML SP to demonstrate how SAML request carries **SP Entity ID** in **Issuer** element and how SAML response carries **SP Entity ID** in the **audience** field.

The following SAML request and truncated SAML response are extracted from a successful SAML Single Sign-On (SSO) provided by **Okta SAML IdP** to **Shibboleth SAML SP** (which is parallel to **Looker SAML SP**).
Shibboleth SAML **SP Entity ID** is https://mycompany.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata

SAML request sent by **Shibboleth SAML SP** to **Okta SAML IdP**

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://mycompany.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST"
Destination="https://dev-806230.oktapreview.com/app/mycompany_shibbolethspdemo/exdgpcskkbjCPYTX90h7/sso/saml"
ID="_9f70ad26f1e69244fade279bc57f7e23"
IssueInstant="2019-05-21T18:40:06Z"
ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
Version="2.0">
<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://mycompany.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata</saml:Issuer>
<samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="1" />
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Truncated SAML response sent by **Okta SAML IdP** to **Shibboleth SAML SP** (only displays the related elements for demo purpose)

```
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
Destination="https://mycompany.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST"
ID="id63794486675331821511177658"
InResponseTo="_9f70ad26f1e69244fade279bc57f7e23"
IssueInstant="2019-05-21T18:40:43.033Z"
Version="2.0">
<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">http://www.okta.com/exdgpcskkbjCPYTX90h7</saml2:Issuer> 
<saml2p:Status xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"> <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" /></saml2p:Status> 
<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
ID="id63794486676092501915396379"
IssueInstant="2019-05-21T18:40:43.033Z"
Version="2.0">
<saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2019-05-21T18:35:43.034Z" NotOnOrAfter="2019-05-21T18:45:43.034Z" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"> 
<saml2:AudienceRestriction>
<saml2:Audience>https://mycompany.example.org/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata</saml2:Audience> 
</saml2:AudienceRestriction>
</saml2:Conditions> 
</saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```